# get Angular-AngularFireAuth-Electron App to work

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication, electron, angularfire2

I made an AngularApp with AngularFireAuth to login the user.
Sice this is a Project for privat use only i wanted to ship it as an electron app to get an exe.

When im running it in Localhost its working fine.
When i run it in electron i get an error:

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise):
FirebaseError: Firebase: This operation is not supported in the environment this application is running on.
"location.protocol" must be http, https or chrome-extension and web storage must be enabled.
(auth/operation-not-supported-in-this-environment).

I tried to find a fix but i but there was nothing around.